# benchmark_rx.py benchmark_tx.py in gnuradio 3.8

Tags: gnuradio

I would like to use [benchmark_rx.py](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/maint-3.7/gr-digital/examples/narrowband/benchmark_rx.py) and [benchmark_tx.py](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/maint-3.7/gr-digital/examples/narrowband/benchmark_tx.py) from gnuradio 3.7 in gnuradio 3.8.

I tried converting these relevant files to python3 which worked but there are other modules missing.
For example in [transmit_path.py](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/maint-3.7/gr-digital/examples/narrowband/transmit_path.py) the module digital.mod_pkts doesn't exist.
I tried converting the mod_pkts  function (gnuradio/digital/pkt.py) to python 3 but I get additional packages that are missing. For example message_source is missing afterwards:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "benchmark_tx_stdin.py", line 270, in <module>
    main()
  File "benchmark_tx_stdin.py", line 214, in main
    tb = my_top_block(mods[options.modulation], options)
  File "benchmark_tx_stdin.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.txpath = transmit_path(modulator, options)
  File "/root/gnuradio/gr-digital/examples/narrowband/transmit_path.py", line 61, in __init__
    pad_for_usrp=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/digital/pkt.py", line 81, in __init__
    self._pkt_input = blocks.message_source(gr.sizeof_char, msgq_limit)
AttributeError: module 'gnuradio.blocks' has no attribute 'message_source'
```

I appreciate any help reproducing these files in gnuradio 3.8

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use benchmark_rx.py and benchmark_tx.py from gnuradio 3.7 in gnuradio 3.8.

You can't. We had to throw out the functionality that benchmark_tx/_rx is based on. It was in fact actively dropping data at unpredictable moments for reasons that none of us could figure out for the better part of a decade.

So, we dropped these python blocks without replacement, which honestly broke very little, because they were just a flaky way of using the modulation mappers and a pulse-shaping filter.

Instead of benchmark_, you should use the packetized communication examples, as explained in [the Official Guided Examples](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org), and as contained as examples in your GNU Radio installation (probably /usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital).

Word on GNU Radio 3.8: Whilst still supported, no forward development is done on it any more. (Which is better than 3.7, where Py2 and bitrotten dependencies make it impossible to sensibly integrate it in our CI infrastructure, so we let it go end-of-life and aren't even able to fix bugs anymore.)